# Axios Action in Redux not "thenable"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I have a fully working setup of React with Redux. In my action file, I use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to make calls to 3rd party API.

After connecting my form component to the Redux store and trying to call the POST action, I am presented with an error saying that I cannot call then on undefined...Funny thing is that the action is still called i.e. the form is submitted to the 3rd party's api right after this console error is thrown. 
I have looked at numerous S/O questions as well as the axios & redux-thunk docs, but can't see what I'm missing. Here is some of the relevant code:

actions.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import _ from 'lodash'
import runtimeEnv from '@mars/heroku-js-runtime-env';
import {apiErrorCatcher} from "../../../utils/errorCatcher"
import {toastr} from 'react-redux-toastr'

const env = runtimeEnv();

export function createProfile(data) {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.post( env.REACT_APP_API_URL  + '/api/profile/', data).then( 
            (res) => {
                toastr.success('Profile added', 'Congratulations on adding your profile')
                return res
            }
        )
        .catch(function (error) {
            apiErrorCatcher(error)
            toastr.error('Oops...', 'Unfortunately an error occurred on our side. Please try again later.')
            return error
        })
    }
}
```

Profile.js

```
...

handleCreateProfile=()=>{
  this.props.actions.createProfile(this.state.data).then( 
    (res) => {console.log(res)}
  )
}

...

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return { actions: bindActionCreators({createProfile}, dispatch) }
}


export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile))
```

index.js

```
...
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(thunk, oidcMiddleware)
  )
);

...
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <OidcProvider store={store} userManager={userManager}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <MuiThemeProvider>
            <App />
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </OidcProvider>
    </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I think that the error might have something to do with promises but I am not 100% confident. Also not sure how to resolve this as I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: where are you getting that error? in `this.props.actions.createProfile(this.state.data).then(...)` ?

Comment: Did you try returning the Promise in your action? `return axios.post(...)`

Comment: Thanks @HiDeo. I managed to fix it before reading your comment but I fixed it by doing exactly what you suggested. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your component method:

```
this.props.actions.createProfile(this.state.data).then( 
  (res) => {console.log(res)}
)
```

becouse action don't return promise, so if you want log your data, or dispatch action you should do it in action createProfile.